# Gauss’s law two concentric cylinders

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

In the answer key, for part b, they take the charge enclosed to be $Q_{enc} = +\frac{Qh}{L}$ where $h$ is the height of the Gaussian cylinder, $L$ is the length of the cylinder with radius $R_1$, and $Q$ is the charge of the cylinder. That doesn’t make a lot of sense to me because I thought you would also have to divide the expression for $Q_{enc}$ by $2\pi R_1$ since $\frac{Q}{2\pi R_1L}$ would give you the surface charge density of the cylinder, and when you multiply that by $h$, you would get $Q_{enc}$. Am I not correct? If not, could you please explain where I’m going wrong?

PS: the answer key I have is from Walter Lewin's MIT course so I doubt it would be incorrect

Comment: Can you share the edition of the book you were following? I am following the 7th edition, but I couldn't find the question mentioned in the assignment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming charge density on the inner shell to be constant $$\sigma= \frac {+Q}{2\pi R_1 l}$$Now for a Gaussian cylinder in the interior region , radius *R* and height *h* $$Q_{enc}=(\frac {+Q}{2\pi R_1 l})(2\pi R_1 h)$$ $$Q_{enc}=\frac {+Qh}{l}$$Instead of taking surface charge density you could've just found out the linear charge density and multiplied it by the height of Gaussian cylinder , both give the same result.

From your comment it seems you are confusing the area terms appearing in Gaussian cylinder and in the evaluation of $Q_{enc} $ $$\epsilon _o \int EdA = \frac{+Qh}{l} $$ $$\epsilon _o E(2\pi Rh)=\frac{+Qh}{l}$$ $$E=\frac {+Qh}{2\pi \epsilon _o Rhl}=\frac {+Q}{2\pi \epsilon _o Rl}$$It is here that 'R' comes into scene , this is quite obvious I think you'll understand.

Comment: But how did you get R1 twice? One is the area of the Gaussian surface, which should have a radius R, and the other is the radius of the small cylinder, which has radius R1. That’s what’s confusing me

Comment: That's quite simple - when you have found out surface charge density of the internal cylinder , why would you want to multiply it by area of some other thing ,that's quite obvious , no?

Comment: It was a simple one , still ^^ can I get an up vote and tick , ofcouse if I've been able to clear your doubt.

Comment: ahhh rookie mistake! Thank you!